# String array not storing data from text file

Tags: java, arrays, split, java.util.scanner

So I have some code that is supposed to use a jfilechooser get a text file use a split and scanner with a colon as a delimeter and store the data into an array. The code and text is as seen below. I have added a segment of code to test if the array length is less than 1 and it always is even though I have set it to to store in a String array. Why is it doing this and how can I get it to store the text from each line of the code into an array of 6 intervals?

```
else if (e.getSource()==readButton) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("Local Disk (C:)");
    if  (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        empFile=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String[] rowData = scan.nextLine().split(":");
        if (rowData.length < 1){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        else if(rowData.length == 5) {
            rowData[4] = "0";
            fName = rowData[0];
            lName = rowData[1];
            position2 = rowData[2];
            firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
            empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);

            c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, 0, empNum);

        }
        else {
            fName = rowData[0];
            lName = rowData[1];
            position2 = rowData[2];
            firstParam = Double.parseDouble(rowData[3]);
            secondParam = Integer.parseInt(rowData[4]);
            empNum = Integer.parseInt(rowData[5]);

            c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2, firstParam, secondParam, empNum);

        }

    }
}
```

> John:Smith:Manufacturing:6.75:120:444
>
> Betty:White:Manager:1200.00:111
>
> Stan:Slimy:Sales:10000.00:332
>
> Betty:Boop:Design:12.50:50:244

Comment: why are you having empfile in citations?

Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");

Comment: wat do u mean? I tried changing it to Scanner scan = new Scanner(empFile); but I got an error.

Comment: what is the name of the file that you are trying to open

Comment: text for assignment 5.txt

Comment: ok. make the empfile without citations and put everything else inside the same if-statement (you can not use the scanner if the if-statement failes anyhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Scanner is taking in a String instead of the variable. Instead of

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
```

Try

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(empFile);
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

> ```
> Scanner(String source)
> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.
> ```

You're currently scanning the string "empFile" instead of the actual file currently.

Comment: I am getting an error when I do empFile instead of empFile

Comment: The error says "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException"

Comment: Do I have to initialize File empFile;?

Comment: put your code inside try catch block , because file handling code comes under checked exception, you cant escape from either try catch or throws

Comment: I have never seen a try/catch or throws what does it do?

Comment: try catch and throws are exception handling mechanism in Java..go through basics of try catch and throws if you want to learn...for your code point of view use throws Exception just after your method name

Comment: @user3530205 To learn about Try-Catch blocks, read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: Ok so I have changed the code and added all of it the try statement is it ok if the catch statement is empty with only the overriden stuff "catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }"

Comment: yea it's ok. If you get an error, the printStackTrace() method will give you information about the error. You might want to disable the printStackTrace() for production though.

Comment: Ya so I'm not gettign an error anymore and I have checked that it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes beacuse you try to use the scanner before there is any chosen file:

```
 if  (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
 {
    empFile=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
 }
 Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
 while(scan.hasNext()){
 }
```

Instead you need to change your code so that you create the scanner only after the file is selected

```
 if  (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
 {
    empFile=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner("empFile");
    while(scan.hasNext()){
    }
}
```